# Problema con for (cursor) e if aniado procedimiento de PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, bucle-for

Lo que pretendo es crear un procedimiento que actualice el precio de venta de una pieza cuyo precio se pasa por parámetro, ésto se hará solo si el precio nuevo es mayor que el existente en la base de datos.De momento quiero hacerlo sin excepciones, y posteriormente agregarlas si puede ser.

La cuestión es que me da un fallo, indicando que existe un IS de más, pero tengo otros similares y en principio creo que la estructura es así, declaro un cursor porque la ejecución de la query da más de una fila, por lo que quiero que entro el cursor localice el precio , y si es mayor lo actualice siendo como parámetro.

```css
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE actualizarPrecio (precioNuevo PIEZAS.PRECIO_VENTA%TYPE,modeloa PIEZAS.MODELO%TYPE)
IS
cursorx IS
  SELECT PRECIO_VENTA FROM PIEZAS WHERE MODELO=modeloa;
  resulta number;
BEGIN
FOR v_reg IN cursorx LOOP
  IF (precioNuevo > precio_venta) THEN
    UPDATE PIEZAS SET PRECIO_VENTA=precioNuevo WHERE MODELO=modeloa;
    resulta:= cursorx%ROWCOUNT;
  ELSE
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No se puede actualizar el precio ');
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursorx;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Filas actualizadas ' ||resulta);
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He visto varias cosas.

1. No estoy seguro de si es obligatorio o no, pero considero una buena
   práctica añadir el tipo de parámetro que se recibe (entrada, salida
   o entrada/salida). Lo hacemos añadiendo un IN entre el nombre del
   parámetro y el tipo.
2. En este caso no es necesario cerrar el cursor ya que se cierra
   automáticamente, al igual que se abre.
3. No veo la declaración del rowtype *v_reg*. Voy a suponer que lo
   declaras en las especificaciones del paquete.
4. En cuando a tu error concretamente, te faltó la palabra CURSOR antes
   del nombre del cursor.

Prueba así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE actualizarPrecio (precioNuevo IN PIEZAS.PRECIO_VENTA%TYPE, modeloa IN PIEZAS.MODELO%TYPE)
IS
    CURSOR cursorx IS
        SELECT PRECIO_VENTA FROM PIEZAS WHERE MODELO=modeloa;

    rowCursorx cursorx%ROWTYPE;
    resulta number;
BEGIN
    FOR rowCursorx IN cursorx LOOP
        IF (precioNuevo > rowCursor.precio_venta) THEN
            UPDATE PIEZAS SET PRECIO_VENTA=precioNuevo WHERE MODELO=modeloa;
            resulta:= cursorx%ROWCOUNT;
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No se puede actualizar el precio ');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Filas actualizadas ' ||resulta);
END;
```

Aunque creo que ha y una forma más sencilla:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE actualizarPrecio (precioNuevo IN PIEZAS.PRECIO_VENTA%TYPE, modeloa IN PIEZAS.MODELO%TYPE)
IS

    resulta NUMBER;

BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO resulta
    FROM PIEZAS
    WHERE MODELO = modeloa
        AND precioNuevo > PRECIO_VENTA;

    IF (resulta > 0) THEN
        UPDATE PIEZAS SET 
            PRECIO_VENTA=precioNuevo 
        WHERE MODELO=modeloa
            AND precioNuevo > PRECIO_VENTA;
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No se puede actualizar el precio ');
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Filas actualizadas ' ||resulta);

END;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la segunda solución funciona, y me parece muy útil el uso de count en lugar del rowcount.De todos modos la 1º opción que me dió no funciona, quería preguntar si, cuando utilizo un cursor, se supone que si saco un campo, en éste caso PRECIO_VENTA, no sería necesario declararlo, puesto que está en el cursor? porque justo el fallo que me está dando ahora es eso, he intentado guardarlo con un ' INTO' en otra variable aparte, e indicar en el IF si esa variable es > que precio_Venta, pero sigue sin funcionar. Gracias

Comment: Ya he actualizado mi respuesta. Tendrías que declarar un rowtype del tipo del cursor. Así puedes hacer referencia a todos los campos que devuelva tu cursor, que en este caso sería sólo PRECIO_VENTA. Pruébalo así a ver que tal. Y recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta si te ha servido, para que sea útil a otros usuarios.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me aclaro algunos vacíos que tenia!